# CSS not working for nested routing in react js

Tags: reactjs, react-router-component

I am new to working with frontend and react js. I have installed a template in my application.
index.html file contain all links and path for css

```
 index.html
 <html lang="en">
 <head>
<meta charset="utf-8" />
<link rel="icon" href="%PUBLIC_URL%/favicon.ico" />
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1" />
<meta name="theme-color" content="#000000" />
 
 { all the css links and scripts goes here}


</body>
</html>
```

This is my app.js file. Here I have mentioned my upper level routes

```
import logo from './logo.svg';
import './App.css';
import Layout from '../src/Components/Layout/Layout'
import LoginScreen from './Components/Login/LoginScreen'
import { BrowserRouter as Router, Route } from "react-router-dom";

function App() {
  return (
     <div className="App">

      <Router>
          <Route path="/pages" component={Layout}/>
          <Route path="/login" component={LoginScreen} exact />
      </Router>

    </div>
  );
 }

 export default App;
```

This is my Layout component which consist of all the screen components (lower level routes)

```
 import React from "react";
 import { BrowserRouter as Router, Route } from "react-router-dom";
 import css_class from "./Layout.module.css";
 import Navbar from '../Navbar/Navbar';
 import TopNavbar from '../TopNavbar/TopNavbar'
 import Home from '../Home/Home'
 import About from '../About/About'
 import OurProject from '../OurProject/OurProject'

 function Layout() {
    return (
      <body>


      <Router>

        
        <TopNavbar/>

        
        <div class="pcoded-main-container">
            <div class="pcoded-wrapper">
                <nav class="pcoded-navbar">
                    <div class="sidebar_toggle"><a href="#"><i class="icon-close icons"></i></a> 
         </div>
                    <div class="pcoded-inner-navbar main-menu">
                        <div class="">
                            <div class="main-menu-header">
                                <img class="img-80 img-radius" style={{height:'7.9em'}} 
                                src="/divylogo.png" alt="User-Profile-Image" />
                            </div>

                            <div class="main-menu-content">
                                <ul>
                                    <li class="more-details">
                                        <a href="user-profile.html"><i class="ti-user"></i>View 
                                         Profile</a>
                                        <a href="#!"><i class="ti-settings"></i>Settings</a>
                                
                                    </li>
                                </ul>
                            </div>
                        </div>

                        
                      <Navbar />
                    </div>
                </nav>
                   
                    <div class="pcoded-inner-content">
                  
                        <div class="main-body">
                            <div class="page-wrapper">

                            
                               
                                <div class="page-body">
                                    

                                    {/* ##################################### */}
                                    <Route path="/" component={Home} exact />
                                    <Route path="/crausal/:id/edit" component={HomeSec2Sub} />
                                    <Route path="/about" component={About} />
                                    <Route path="/ourproject" component={OurProject} />
                                    <Route path="/projects" component={Projects} />
                                    {/* ##################################### */}
                                </div>
                            
                            
                              
                            </div>
                        </div>
                   

                        <div id="styleSelector">

                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        </div>
</div>


<script src="assets/js/jquery.mCustomScrollbar.concat.min.js "></script>


<script src="assets/js/pcoded.min.js"></script>
<script src="assets/js/vertical/vertical-layout.min.js "></script>

<script type="text/javascript" src="assets/js/script.js "></script>
</Router>
</body>

);
}

export default Layout;
```

But somehow my pages i.e layout components are not getting any css.
In my app.js file if I change the route of Layout component from (pages/) to (/), then everything works.
But if I use (pages/ as route) I am not getting any css for my sub routes mentioned in Layout component.

Comment: First step, remove the nested `Router` component, you need only one in your app. Can you clarify in better detail about what CSS the (*not-so-nested since they are still at the root*) "nested" aren't getting?

Comment: But how would I differentiate between login and rest of my pages. I have a login page with its css and a layout that is used by rest of the other pages.

Comment: In my app.js for my layout component path if I use  if i use this (                            <Router>
        <Route path="/" component={Layout}/>
        <Route path="/login" component={LoginScreen} exact />
      </Router>) things are ok. But when I use this                                    (      <Router>
        <Route path="/pages" component={Layout}/>
        <Route path="/login" component={LoginScreen} exact />
      </Router>). All the components inside my Layout looses all of its css

Comment: I'm not sure I follow your question... as soon as the path is anything other than "/pages" then `Layout` component is no longer mounted (*along with the css it imported*). Are you wanting to *actually* nest those other routes under "/pages", like "/pages/about", etc...?

Comment: Yes I want it like this ("pages/about" etc). What I am saying is  if I give path like this (<Route path="/" component={Layout}/>) It works. But If I use anything else with ("/") this like ("/pages", "/subfiles" etc) The css does not works for them

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## Issue

> What I am saying is if I give path like this (`<Route path="/" component={Layout}/>`) It works. But If I use anything else with ("/")
> this like ("/pages", "/subfiles" etc) The css does not works for them.

As soon as the path is anything other than "/pages" then `Layout` component is no longer mounted (*along with the css it imported*). The reason it works with "/" is because "/" is a path prefix ***for all paths*** and will always match.

> Yes I want it like this ("pages/about" etc).

## Solution

If you want "/pages" as a path prefix to the nested paths then they need to actually be nested.

1. Import `Switch` and `useRouteMatch` hook from `react-router-dom`. The `useRouteMatch` hook allows you to access the current path so you can build nested routes upon it, and the `Switch` is so you are matching and rendering only one sub-route.
2. Remove the nested `Router` component, you need only one `Router` component to provide a routing context.
3. Remove the `body` and `script` tags. You need only one `body` tag per HTML document and the script tags can be declared in your `index.html` file.

Code:

```
import { Route, Switch, useRouteMatch } from "react-router-dom";

function Layout() {
  const { path } = useRouteMatch();

  return (
    <>
      <TopNavbar />

      <div class="pcoded-main-container">
        <div class="pcoded-wrapper">
          ...

          <div class="pcoded-inner-content">
            <div class="main-body">
              <div class="page-wrapper">
                <div class="page-body">
                  <Switch>
                    <Route
                      path={`${path}/crausal/:id/edit`}
                      component={HomeSec2Sub}
                    />
                    <Route path={`${path}/about`} component={About} />
                    <Route path={`${path}/ourproject`} component={OurProject} />
                    <Route path={`${path}/projects`} component={Projects} />
                    <Route path={path} component={Home} />
                  </Switch>
                </div>
              </div>
            </div>

            <div id="styleSelector"></div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </>
  );
}
```

For more see [nesting example](https://reactrouter.com/web/example/nesting) from `react-router-dom`.

Answer (score 5):

If it is the same problem I had, solution is to use absolute paths (beginning with /) for all assets in your index.html file.

As index.html is a static file, when you load it on a route as /products/productId, the relative path points to /products/style.css, where file is not found.

So in index.html change this:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="./style.css" media="all" />
```

For this:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="/style.css" media="all" />
```

Comment: Most accurate answer. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

I also have the same problem. My CSS file giving `status code` of 500 on nested routes in `react-router-dom` but working fine with root route.

[image: error on reading css file]

I fix this issue using following step:

1. remove my CSS file from public/main.css
2. add my css file at source root level -> src/main.css
3. import my css file into index.js -> `import './main.css';`

P.S - I'm using create-react-app